# How come that MIB's and his mother's bodies were 40-50 years old when found by Jack and Kate?

Tags: lost

In episode 6, after they get rid of the bees, Kate and Jack find two bodies in the caves. We, later, get to know that they are Jacob's twin's and his mother's bodies. At that point, Jack says (at ~13:45): "It takes 40 to 50 years for clothing to degrade like this".

Shouldn't the bodies be much older?

Comment: Are you still watching the show, and are you aware of the shows finale? because the answer to this question is a *big spoiler* if not.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional, yeah. I'm watching the show for the fourth time now. Don't worry.

Comment: there's your answer then. For any questions over rules of reality/physics being broken: see final episode.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional, I'm not sure I follow.

Comment: Are you asking why the clothing is only 40-50 years old or asking why the bodies haven't decomposed longer, since we know how old MIB and his mother are?

Comment: @Jared, the clothing mainly, but also the bodies. I thought the two were connected.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional Time to speak it out loudly (in a proper answer so to say), I guess.

Comment: I believe the industry term is an "oopsie". aka retcon. Or, you know, Jack isn't really qualified to judge corpse age.

Comment: If it helps, assume he meant "at least" rather than "at most".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The comments have been misleading. The show's creators have been very clear about the fact that they were not dead the whole time, only during the flash-sideways in season 6. The explanation given on the official podcast by Damon Lindelof and Carlton Cuse for what Jack says is simply that he isn't an anthropologist or archaeologist, so he misjudged the age of the clothes by about 2000 years.

I, for one, don't quite believe this explanation, and I think it's simply that the original vision for Adam and Eve was for them to be characters from a much more recent time, and Jack's estimate was originally intended to be accurate. But, later on, the story took a different direction.